# What does (^?)* mean in this regex?

Tags: regex, lua

I have this regex:

```
^(^?)*\?(.*)$
```

If I understand correctly, this is the breakdown of what it does:

- ^ - start matching from the beginning of the string
- (^?)* - I don't know know, but it stores it in $1
- \? - matches a question mark
- (.*)$ - matches anything until the end of the string

So what does (^?)* mean?

Comment: Could you specify the regex engine being used here?

Comment: Lua! http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html

Comment: @doremi: After I read the doc, Lua's regex is quite a beast of its own. The meaning of the regex may change whether it is used with gmatch or match.

Comment: You should accept RBerteig's answer since it's the most relevant to lua and he explains it in much more detail on what's happening.

Comment: Lua patterns are deceptively similar to regexp, but *are not the same*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `(^?)` is simply looking for the literal character `^`.  The `^` character in a regex pattern only has special meaning when used as the first character of the pattern or the first character in a grouping match `[]`.  When used outside those 2 positions the `^` is interpreted literally meaning in looks for the `^` character in the input string

Note: Whether or not `^` outside of the first and grouping position is interpreted literally is regex engine specific.  I'm not familiar enough with LUA to state which it does

Comment: Hmm. I still don't get it. Can you give me an example of a string where this would match? FYI - this is being used on a url with a query string.

Comment: no comment on the pointelessness of `(^?)*`? i.e. it's a 0 or one character match, matching only the character `^`, matching 0 to many times  - the same (probably) as `(^*)` unless the multiple groups are being used

Comment: It could be a bad regex as it would provided to me by someone else. That's part of the reason why I'm trying to understand what it does.

Comment: @AD7six agreed that's most likely bogus. It *could* be valid it certain regex engines (Vim with no magic for example) but that setting would also invalidate my answer.  Very likely bogus but wanted to know the regex engine before I dove outside the specifics of the question

Comment: @JaredPar: Your example is very confusing. .NET is a pretty bad example, since it has special meaning in every single case you have there. It may be true that Lua treat `^` as literal character, but let me double check.

Comment: @nhahtdh there are 5 occurrences of `^` in my patterns, only 3 have special meaning.

Comment: @JaredPar: All of them has special meaning. I have checked it on regexhero (.NET tester). I think you should use `Match` instead of `IsMatch` to check in detail what is actually matched: http://ideone.com/T6Jyxu

Comment: @nhahtdh don't believe that's correct.  The second `^` is interpreted literally. I've tested this locally

Comment: @JaredPar: Maybe with Lua, but not with .NET. Have you tried my code on ideone?

Answer (score 7):

Lua does not have a conventional regexp language, it has Lua patterns in its place. While they look a lot like regexp, Lua patterns are a distinct language of their own that has a simpler set of rules and most importantly lacks grouping and alternation features.

Interpreted as a Lua pattern, the example will surprising a longtime regexp user since so many details are different.

Lua patterns are [described](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html) [in](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html), and at a first glance are similar enough to a conventional regexp to cause confusion. The biggest differences are probably the lack of an alternation operator `|`, parenthesis are only used to mark captures, quantifiers (`?`, `-`, `+`, and `*`) only apply to a character or character class, and `%` is the escape character not `\`. A big clue that this example was probably not written with Lua in mind is the lack of the Lua pattern quoting character `%` applied to any (or ideally, all) of the non-alphanumeric characters in the pattern string, and the suspicious use of `\?` which smells like a conventional regexp to match a single literal `?`.

The simple answer to the question asked is: `(^?)*` is not a recommended form, and would match `^*` or `*`, capturing the presence or absence of the caret. If that were the intended effect, then I would write it as `(%^?)%*` to make that clearer.

To see why this is the case, let's take the pattern given and analyze it as a Lua pattern. The entire pattern is:

```
^(^?)*\?(.*)$
```

Handed to `string.match()`, it would be interpreted as follows:

`^` anchors the match to the beginning of the string.

`(` marks the beginning of the first capture.

`^` is not at the beginning of the pattern or a character class, so it matches a literal `^` character. For clarity that should likely have been written as `%^`.

`?` matches exactly zero or one of the previous character.

`)` marks the end of the first capture.

`*` is not after something that can be quantified so it matches a literal `*` character. For clarity that should likely have been written as `%*`.

`\` in a pattern matches itself, it is not an escape character in the pattern language. However, it *is* an escape character in a Lua short string literal, making the following character not special to the string literal parser which in this case is moot because the `?` that follows was not special to it in any case. So if the pattern were enclosed in double or single quotes, then the `\` would be absorbed by string parsing. If written in a long string (as `[[^(^?)*\?(.*)$]]`, the backslash would survive the string parser, to appear in the pattern.

`?` matches exactly zero or one of the previous character.

`(` marks the beginning the second capture.

`.` matches any character at all, effectively a synonym for the class `[\000-\255]` (remember, in Lua numeric escapes are in decimal not octal as in C).

`*` matches zero or more of the previous character, greedily.

`)` marks the end of the second capture.

`$` anchors the pattern to the end of the string.

So it matches and captures an optional `^` at the beginning of the string, followed by `*`, then an optional `\` which is not captured, and captures the entire rest of the string. `string.match` would return two strings on success (either or both of which might be zero length), or `nil` on failure.

**Edit:** I've fixed some typos, and corrected an error in my answer, noticed by [Egor](/users/6834680/egor-skriptunoff) in a comment. I forgot that in patterns, special symbols loose their specialness when in a spot where it can't apply. That makes the first asterisk match a literal asterisk rather than be an error. The cascade of that falls through most of the answer.

Note that if you really want a true regexp in Lua, there are libraries available that will provide it. That said, the built-in pattern language is quite powerful. If it is not sufficient, then you might be best off adopting a full parser, and use [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/) which can do everything a regexp can and more. It even comes with a module that provides a complete regexp syntax that is translated into an LPeg grammar for execution.

Comment: Actually, the first `*` is not an error, it is just magic-less.  For example, `assert(string.match("^*", "^(^?)*"))`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I think you are right. The effect is much the same, the pattern doesn't match what a regex user thinks it would match.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the (^?) refers to the previous string "^" meaning the literal character ^ as Jared has said. Check out regexlib for any further deciphering.

For all your Regex needs: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the intent of the creator of the expression was to match any number of ^ before the question mark, but only wanted to *capture* the first instance of ^. However, it may not be a valid expression depending on the engine, as others have stated.